# Reformat code in Atom editor?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I want to try Atom editor, and install it, install atom beautify also, to reformat php/html/js code. But I can't find shortcut and I don't now how to use it. I want to mark all code and to click some shortcut and reformat it (like most IDEs). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the auto indent command from the command palette `cmd-shift-p` or you can follow these instructions to make a key binding:

A shortcut for formatting the file content or a portion of code can be made by putting this in your keymap file:

```
`'.editor:not(.mini)': 'alt-cmd-l': 'editor:auto-indent'`
```

You could try to add a key mapping (Atom > Open Your Keymap [on Windows: File > Settings > Keybindings > "your keymap file"]) like this

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-alt-l': 'editor:auto-indent'
```

Now ctrl-alt-l will be your shortcut once you set

Comment: This only changes indent and doesn't reflow code (ie add newlines to break up expressions), it's basically useless